# print value in round robbin style

Tags: java

Sample code

```
int count=0;
while(true)
{ 
if(count>3)
System.out.print("value"+count);
count=count+1;
}
```

Required Output:

```
Value 0
Value 1
Value 2
Value 0
Value 1
Value 2
```

Whenever control flows within while loop it should print above value repeatedly. How to change above code?

Comment: do you really want it to run infinitely?

Comment: @RohitJain this will throw a OutOfMemoryException after a while

Comment: @MarcoForberg It runs.Check it please. Run and wait a while.

Comment: okay will run forever but will start showing negative values then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
while (true)
{
    if (count > 2)
    {
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Value " + count);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pinky glad i could help :) if something helps you upvote and accept it

Comment: You're doing 7 iteration for what requires just 6. That means, for every 6 iteration, you're doing 1 extra iteration.

Comment: @RohitJain that's true! but seriously: this code is readable and doesn't need to be performant.

Comment: Result starts with value1value2value0 etc. I need result like value0value1value2value0 etc.

Answer (score 5):

Use Modulus.

```
int count = 0;

while(true) {
   System.out.println("Value " + count); 
   count = ++count % 3;     
}
```

Comment: No colon in his sample output, otherwise this is the cleanest answer so far.

Comment: Edited. Will print before updating value. Should start with 0.

Comment: `count` cycles between `0` and `2`. It won't overflow. The computer might explode though.

Comment: thats true! sorry! my sample was wrong when i tested something

Comment: more efficient than my answer, but not so readable for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

This might be the shortest variant

```
for(int count = 0; ; count = ++count % 3) {
    System.out.println("Value " + count);
}
```

Comment: `while (true) System.out.println("Value " + (count++) % 3);` is shorter ;-)

Comment: @tobias_k true ;) btw which exception is thrown when count reaches the upper limit of int? didn't work with java in a while

Comment: @MarcoForberg. None. Integer overflow never throws exception in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but remember to break at some condition or it will go in infinite loop :

```
        int count = 0;
        int max = 3;
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("Value " + count);
            count++;
            count %= (max + 1);
        }
```